# Ideas wanted: how to do live refresh of web page. Use ajax? Something else?

Tags: php, ajax, algorithm

So, I have made a script that attempts to solve a slitherlink puzzle ( not relevant to the question, but here are the rules: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slitherlink )

The script runs at: http://www.kokkorogiannis.gr/slitherlink/ and it solves the puzzles I have given it.

When the algorithm runs, it goes through many steps. In each step it solves a little bit of the puzzle. For example, all the steps for this puzzle are at: http://www.kokkorogiannis.gr/slitherlink/?showdos=1

Now, I want to do the following: Instead of showing each step (each board state) the one under the other, I want to show the initial board, and then, as I walk through my script, to change the board, showing its progress.

Problems:
I know that php is server side only, so once it sends something, there is no way to modify it.
I could use javascript and ajax, and program my javascript, every second or so, to ask the server for the changes to show, but: ajax is asynchronous. Each request stands alone, so the server would not know that to show next.

One solution would be to run the algorithm once (and not each time the page gets requested), save the state, or the changes in a db, and just use php and js to show it (sending the next state, or the changes each time they get requested). But I dont like this idea, as it does not solve the puzzle, just shows different states (and any modifications to the algorithm don't get reflected).

Working on an other technology (not web), for example at a desktop or mobile app, I could do what I wanted, show the progress. But how could I do that in the web?

K.

Comment: How long does it take the php server to run the algorithm on one puzzle?

Comment: the biggest/hardest ones I have put in until now (from 20x20 from Krazydad's website at http://krazydad.com/slitherlink/index.php?fmt=to_lg ), take around 120 seconds (using 1 level of brute force for the last part of the puzzle). http://www.kokkorogiannis.gr/slitherlink/index.php?brute=1&preset=12 (look at the bottom of the page, it says the time it took whenever you run it).

Comment: My hunch is that if you want actual real-time output of the PHP server's progress, the PHP page running the algorithm would have to save its progress periodically either to a DB or to new file/s. Another page (the one that the user sees) would try to access that output at short intervals. (To make sure you are displaying the progress reports in order, a simple numbered id for each stage could suffice.)

Comment: I ended up doing it with ajax, using REST. The client sends the current state, and the server decides based on that current state each time. http://www.kokkorogiannis.gr/slitherlink/index2.php

Comment: So if I'm looking at 'index2.php,' does the server run the algorithm again each time the ajax update-request is made?

Comment: Yes, but it does not compute the whole solution every time. Just the next stage.